# Delay the output of a button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have a button load the next scene in my game, but I also want it to wait a second or so before changing scenes where a small audio clip can be played.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NextScene : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void MoveToScene(int sceneId)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneId);
    }
}
```

On my button in Unity, the "On Click()" function has to things it does. One is it runs the script above, and plays a sound. I want to delay the switch scenes function, but not the sound. If there was a way to delay the changescene function in the script then that would work maybe?

Comment: UX wise i would be quite bad to have a delay after a user interaction without having a kind of progress feedback. Do you want the delay only so the sounds can finish playing? (-> rather use a DontDestroyOnLoad AudioSource and PlayOneShot so the sound can continue playing while the scene is switched )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NextScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void MoveToScene(int sceneId)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAfterDelay(sceneId, 1.0f)); // 1.0f is the delay in seconds
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadSceneAfterDelay(int sceneId, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneId);
    }
}
```

This should do what you're wanting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).